# What is the best way to handle page switching?

Tags: php

Currently I use `switch($_GET['page'])` to put it simply. This is a simple solution and works basically anywhere.

However, sadly some of the projects have grown so much, that I'm wondering, if there is a better..faster method for this?

This is my base for, how I switch pages currently:

```
// There is more complex .htacces to translation of friendly-urls behind it, but for example sake, these variables are being produced:
$lext = array(
    'parent_page' => 'about-us',
    'child_page' => 'map-to-somewhere',
    'child_id' => NULL, // if it would be a article or something, it would be example.com/{parent_page}/{child_id}-some-friendly-url.html
);

switch ($lext['parent_page']) {
    case 'about-us':
        // about us page
    break;
    case '':
        // home
    break;
    default:
        // 404
    break;
}
```

Inside the switch cases, it either triggers a function or includes a file. As it turned out to produce fastest page load results.

So I'm wondering, for a large amount of traffic and your "index.php" aka. the landing file getting alot of hits. What would be the fastest and most simplest solution?
As the simplest or stupidest solutions seem to produce the best results, I woulnt be suprised if:

```
if ($lext['parent_page'] == 'about-us') {
    // about us page
} else if ($lext['parent_page'] == '') {
    // home
} else {
    // 404
}
```

..would be faster and better beforming then `switch()`.

I have already searched SO for similar questions and tested all the answers, but the ones I have found, do not perform better.

Comment: How many pages are we talking about here? Because if you only have 3 pages I doubt performance will increase if you use a different method.

Comment: @TomKriek The site, that gets alot of hits, has less then 10 pages. But may have more child pages. However, they are being handled from the functions or includes inside. So currently, this page switching part is slowing up page load the most. Other projects, have small traffic and it isn't any sort of problem. But this one site has around 600 users currently all the time, and its becoming problematic.

Comment: duplicate of a duplicate of a duplicate... search.

Comment: Pointless premature optimization. Write clean code. "currently, this page switching part is slowing up page load the most." - I don't believe you. How have you measured this?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath We have setup microtime measures for the test site, that basically tracks timestamp after every action.

Comment: I still don't believe you. What's an action? Honestly, the whole presupposition that a small code snipet like that takes most of the time sounds utter rubbish to me. Show evidence.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Well, if you mean under that. That this method of handling page switching, is OK. Then I really don't have anything else to add or ask. But I personally feel, that its not the proper way to do it, and better programmers do it differently?

Comment: Yeah, it's a rubbish way. But thinking in terms of *performance* is just a horrible idea.

Comment: @KalleH.Väravas Have you checked that your host provider didn't set your bandwidth too low?

Comment: @TomKriek No, thats not the problem. We have 10 TB included with the package. And unlimited extra bandwidth, with low cost. But thankfully CDN, keeps everything in check. Im just wondering, if there is an alternative method, that is better, then what I'm used to using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple answers to this. Depends largely on your project and how much refactoring you want to do. My concern would not be speed so much as code scalability and ease of maintenance. A `switch` with anything but a LOT of cases probably isn't going to cause you any noticeable slow-down vs. if-else or other means.

One approach might be to move into the world of MVC frameworks, which typically have a controller method per page, allowing you a nice, clean split in your code. For example, with Code Igniter you specify your pages thusly:

```
class MySite {

    /* constructor etc */

    public function page_1() {
        //this is called on visits to /page_1
        //load a view for this page, etc
    }

    public function page_13() {
        //this is called on visits to /page_3
        //load a view for this page, etc
    }

}
```

A simpler approach might be to make a JSON data file of the available cases and what should happen in each one.

```
{
    "page_1": {"inc": "page_1.php"},
    "page_13": {"func:": "some_func"},
}
```

Then, in your PHP:

```
//get data
$data = @file_get_contents($fp = 'pages_data.txt') or die("Couldn't load ".$fp);
$data = json_decode($data, 1);

//look for requested page in data - if found, include file or run function...
if (isset($data[$lext['parent_page']])) {

    $item = $data[$lext['parent_page']];

    //...include file
    if (isset($item['inc']) && file_exists($item['inc']))
        include $item['inc'];

    //...run function
    else if (isset($item'func']) && function_exists($item['func']))
        $item['func']();

} else
    //404...
}
```

Comment: I see, very interesting approach. I'm gonna give it a try. As JSON, we use for settings at the moment. As getting them from SQL or memcaching them, was slower.

Comment: 5 years later: "A switch with anything but a LOT of cases probably isn't going to cause you any noticeable slow-down vs. if-else or other means." - Project has grown further, the switch stayed -- no problems, it works.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how you manage your pages. If you have to `require` every page file, than you always can load that file by simply:

```
$page = isset($_REQUEST['page']) ? $_REQUEST['page'] : 'index';

if (file_exists(__DIR__.'/views/'.$page.'.php')) {
    require(__DIR__.'/views/'.$page.'.php');
} else {
   switch ($page) {
       // Custom rules that does not fit to previous rule.
   }
}
```

---

I suggest using class / action structure to dynamically load requested page (like most frameworks).

```
[index.php]

$route = isset($_REQUEST['route']) ? $_REQUEST['route'] : 'index';
$page = explode('/', $route);

require_once(__DIR__.'/controller/'.ucfirst($route[0]).'Controller.php');

$className = ucfirst($route[0]).'Controller';
$class = new $className();
$class->{$route[1]}();
```

**SOME WARNINGS**

Always try to whitelist your requests, don't forget empty values defaults, use `$_REQUEST` if you may pass route information via POST or GET.

---

For SEO Url, you will be using `.htaccess` and database.